# Java: How to get RGB-values of an image?

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb, grayscale

I know there are quite a few similar questions out there, but none of them seemed to solve my problem. I want to read the pixel values of an image and store them in a double array. Since the images are only grayscale, I converted the RGB-values to an grayscale value. I also changed the range of values from `0-255` to `0-1`.

That's my code:

```java
public static double[] getValues(String path) {
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        double[] values = new double[width * height];

        int index = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(y, x));
                int gray = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
                values[index++] = gray / 255d;
            }
        }

        return values;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

However, when I use this to convert a black image to double values I expect only `0.0` as values in the array. But what I get looks somewhat like the following:
`[0.058823529411764705, 0.058823529411764705, 0.058823529411764705, ...]`

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line ...

```java
int gray = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
```

... to ...

```java
int gray = color.getRed();
```

A grayscaled pixel has all it's color channels having the same value. You don't need to do any arithmetic operations there.

---

Looking at the rest of your code, I don't see any mistake. The problem is most likely that the *black* color you have there is not black. Black is RGB of `(0, 0, 0)`.

---

Multiplying your result by 255 gives me around 15. So the color is RGB of `(15, 15, 15)` which is `#0F0F0F`. This is pretty dark but don't mistake it with true black that is `#000000`.

Comment: You were right... I'm using the images to train a neural network, so to test it I just opened my image editing software and draw some numbers. I didnt notice the 2 standard colors were not at their default values black/white, but the black was still a very dark gray from previous work... Thank you, sometimes it's the simple things :D